# Symfony error in Dynamic Form yii2

Tags: yii2

I did a composer update in my yii2 project and after that I'm getting syntax error, unexpected '?' in /vendor/symfony folder in several places dom-crawler etc. in yii2.

I'm only getting error while I'm opening form with yii2 dynamic form. The other view files are working fine.

```
composer.json file - 
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "~1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "reportico/yii2-reportico": "dev-master",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "*",
        "kartik-v/dependent-dropdown": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform": "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "beaten-sect0r/yii2-db-manager": "*",
        "spanjeta/yii2-backup": "*",
        "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

php version - 7.0.2

I tried to remove vendor directory, clear cache and composer install again with same result.

Comment: just remove the `vendor` directory and run composer install again

Comment: it uses `symfony/dom-crawler` and `"symfony/css-selector": "~2.8|~3.0",` that might be having trouble. you can verify by using `composer show -i` on project root,  to look what is installed and which version

Comment: You're probably trying to use packages that require PHP 7.1 on pre-7.1 environment. Please share your `composer.json` content and your PHP version.

Comment: I've updated the question some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should lock your PHP version in `composer.json` config:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0"
    }
},
```

It looks like you're using different PHP version for installing packages, so Composer is installing packages that require PHP 7.1. Adding this will force Composer to install versions for PHP 7.0.

Second, you should really avoid constraints like `>=2.0.6`, `@dev` or `*`. This will allow Composer to upgrade packages to new major version which may (and probably will) introduce backward compatibility break. So even if package will work on PHP 7.0, it may break your app.

Comment: Hi, the colon after platform is shown as pink mark in sublime text.. And secondly, do we need a composer update after it.

Comment: Yes, you need to run `composer update` after this change. You may even need to delete `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` before update - composer-asset-plugin has known bug with downgrading packages.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I spent more than 4 hours trying to find a way around this error until I came to your answer. Thanks, Worked like a miracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your php version. It worked with me.

Comment: From what, to what? Please explain

Comment: I'm getting syntax error, unexpected '?' in /vendor/symfony folder in several places dom-crawler etc. in yii2.
His/Her question was somethimg like this.